# Unexpected argument passing dictionary to function with **kwargs python3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyword-argument

I'm trying to pass a dictionary to a function called solve_slopeint() using **kwargs because the values in the dictionary could sometimes be None depending on the user input. When I try to do that, I get a TypeError saying:

```
solve_slopeint() takes 0 positional arguments but one was given
```

Here's the whole process of what's happening:

1. arg_dict values set to None and program asks a question
2. User says yes. A function is then called and starts with another question. The user inputs 2
3. User is asked to enter point 1 and then asked to enter point 2
4. Those 2 points are returned to the parent function as a list of lists.
5. arg_dict accesses those values and sets them to its corresponding keys.
6. solve_slopeint() is called with arg_dict as the parameter.

Here is the code that you need to see:

**main.py**

```
def slope_intercept():
    arg_dict = {
        "point1": None,
        "point2": None,
        "slope": None,
        "y-intercept": None
    }
    while True:
        question1 = input("Were you given any points that the line passes through? (y/n): ")
        if question1 == 'y':
            point_list = passing_points()
            if len(point_list) == 2:
                arg_dict["point1"] = point_list[0]
                arg_dict["point2"] = point_list[1]
                solve_slopeint(arg_dict)
```

**functions.py**

```
def passing_points():
    while True:
        num_points = input("How many points were you given?: ")
        try:
            num_points = int(num_points)
        elif num_points == 2:
            point1_list = []
            point2_list = []

            while True:
                point1 = input("Enter point 1 in the format x,y: ")
            while True:
                point2 = input("Enter point 2 in the format x,y: ")
    return [point1_list, point2_list]
```

**solve_functions.py**

```
def solve_slopeint(**kwargs):
    print("Equation solved!")
```

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoZMB.png) to see the output of the debugger in PyCharm.

Just so people know, I left out a lot of error checking making sure that the user doesn't intentionally or accidentally input something wrong. If I left out some code that makes this code here not understandable, please tell me in the comments.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: in `slope_intercept()` try `solve_slopeint(**arg_dict)` in order to unpack `arg_dict`.

Comment: I still get the same error. However, I have another function calling the slope_intercept() function because the user has to choose an equation. Should I put **arg_dict in the parent function's parameter list even though arg_dict is defined in slope_intercept? or what should I do?

Comment: Please, edit your question to include [mre] as well as the full traceback. I don't see how you will get the same error if you made the change as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong calling the `solve_slopeint` function.

Do it like this:

```
def slope_intercept():
    arg_dict = {
        "point1": None,
        "point2": None,
        "slope": None,
        "y-intercept": None
    }
    while True:
        question1 = input("Were you given any points that the line passes through? (y/n): ")
        if question1 == 'y':
            point_list = passing_points()
            if len(point_list) == 2:
                arg_dict["point1"] = point_list[0]
                arg_dict["point2"] = point_list[1]
                solve_slopeint(**arg_dict)
                # Or:
                # solve_slopeint(point1=point_list[0], point2=point_list[1])
```